# Check collisions between two objects in java

Tags: java, collision-detection

I have a method that checks if the player and the item are intersecting and adds the item to the inventory, but the method only seems to work if the rectangles are completely overlapping, and the item is not made null unless i specifically say so in the panel. Otherwise, the item keeps moving around the panel as if nothing happened.

```
public boolean obtainItem(Item item)
{
    if (item.moveable)
    {
        Rectangle p = getBounds();
        Rectangle i = item.getBounds();
        if (p.intersects(i))
        {
            inventory.add(item);
            i = null;
            System.out.println("hello");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The code for my getBounds() methods are

public Rectangle getBounds()
    {
        bounds = new Rectangle(x, y, 40, 40);
        return bounds;
    }

And it is returning the correct bounds

Comment: Your code looks good. Print out the bounds of both, and make sure those are what you expect them to be

Comment: And you don't think showing us the `Rectangle.intersects()` method would be useful?

Comment: That's actually java.awt.Rectangle method, right (or at least I hope so)

Comment: Ah. That wasn't obvious to me. Plus my Eclipse told me there was no `Rectangle` class in the runtime library - but that's because I've told it to completely hide `java.awt.*`! LOL

Answer (score 2):

The [Javadoc for Rectangle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/Rectangle.html) clearly suggests that if the intersection is non zero then `rectangle.intersects()` return `true` otherwise `false`.

Could it be possible that your `item.getBounds()` and `getBounds()` methods are returning bounds relative to different bounding components?

Answer (score 1):

> item is not made null unless i specifically say so in the panel.

Why should it be otherwise?  `i = null;` just sets the local variable i to null.

Answer (score 0):

All of that code looks fine, assuming you are using java.awt.Rectangle as iluxa pointed out.  It is most likely an error in your Item class.  Can you post that?